# issue in xsd validation

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd, wsdl

I am getting below error during xsd valisdation:

Error: src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'ns0:dachExceptionData'. It was detected that 'ns0:dachExceptionData' is in namespace 'http://com.dachser.edi.ext.api.ping.service.PingEdiExtService', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:/C:/Users/anujkumar/Downloads/wsdl%20test/pingEdiExtService.wsdl'. If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'ns0:dachExceptionData' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'file:/C:/Users/anujkumar/Downloads/wsdl%20test/pingEdiExtService.wsdl'. line number: 2 column number: 96 literal system id file:/C:/Users/anujkumar/Downloads/wsdl%20test/pingEdiExtService.wsdl

WSDL is:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="PingEdiExtServiceSoapImplService" targetNamespace="http://com.dachser.edi.ext.api.ping.service.PingEdiExtService"><wsdl:types><xs:schema elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://com.dachser.edi.ext.api.ping.service.PingEdiExtService" version="1.0"><xs:element name="ping" type="tns:ping"/><xs:element name="pingResponse" type="tns:pingResponse"/><xs:complexType name="ping"><xs:sequence/></xs:complexType><xs:complexType name="pingResponse"><xs:sequence><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/></xs:sequence></xs:complexType><xs:complexType name="dachExceptionData"><xs:sequence><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="cause" type="xs:string"/><xs:element name="expType" type="xs:int"/><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="message" type="xs:string"/></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:schema><xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://exception.ws.dachser.com"><xsd:element name="DachUncheckedExceptionSoap" nillable="true" type="ns0:dachExceptionData"/></xsd:schema></wsdl:types><wsdl:message name="DachUncheckedExceptionSoap"><wsdl:part element="ns1:DachUncheckedExceptionSoap" name="DachUncheckedExceptionSoap">
    </wsdl:part></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="ping"><wsdl:part element="tns:ping" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="pingResponse"><wsdl:part element="tns:pingResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part></wsdl:message><wsdl:portType name="PingEdiExtServiceSoapImpl"><wsdl:operation name="ping"><wsdl:input message="tns:ping" name="ping">
    </wsdl:input><wsdl:output message="tns:pingResponse" name="pingResponse">
    </wsdl:output><wsdl:fault message="tns:DachUncheckedExceptionSoap" name="DachUncheckedExceptionSoap">
    </wsdl:fault></wsdl:operation></wsdl:portType><wsdl:binding name="PingEdiExtServiceSoapImplServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:PingEdiExtServiceSoapImpl"><soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/><wsdl:operation name="ping"><soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/><wsdl:input name="ping"><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input><wsdl:output name="pingResponse"><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output><wsdl:fault name="DachUncheckedExceptionSoap"><soap:fault name="DachUncheckedExceptionSoap" use="literal"/></wsdl:fault></wsdl:operation></wsdl:binding><wsdl:service name="PingEdiExtServiceSoapImplService"><wsdl:port binding="tns:PingEdiExtServiceSoapImplServiceSoapBinding" name="PingEdiExtServiceSoapImplPort"><soap:address location="https://edi.dachser.com/soap/ext/pingEdiExtService"/></wsdl:port></wsdl:service></wsdl:definitions>
```

Although I can validate this wsdl at https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/

What is wrong with wsdl?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem I see it is not well-defined some namespaces. I have added them ( xmlns:tns="http://com.dachser.edi.ext.api.ping.service.PingEdiExtService" xmlns:ns0="http://exception.ws.dachser.com"
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/") into definitions.

The entire wsdl has the following definition:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="PingEdiExtServiceSoapImplService" targetNamespace="http://com.dachser.edi.ext.api.ping.service.PingEdiExtService"
                  xmlns:tns="http://com.dachser.edi.ext.api.ping.service.PingEdiExtService" xmlns:ns0="http://exception.ws.dachser.com"
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://com.dachser.edi.ext.api.ping.service.PingEdiExtService"
               xmlns:tns="http://com.dachser.edi.ext.api.ping.service.PingEdiExtService" version="1.0">
      <xs:element name="ping" type="tns:ping"/>
      <xs:element name="pingResponse" type="tns:pingResponse"/>
      <xs:complexType name="ping">
        <xs:sequence/>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="pingResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://exception.ws.dachser.com"
               xmlns:ns0="http://exception.ws.dachser.com">
      <xs:element name="DachUncheckedExceptionSoap" nillable="true" type="ns0:dachExceptionData"/>
      <xs:complexType name="dachExceptionData">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="cause" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="expType" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="message" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="DachUncheckedExceptionSoap">
    <wsdl:part name="DachUncheckedExceptionSoap" element="ns0:DachUncheckedExceptionSoap"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="ping">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:ping" name="parameters"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="pingResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:pingResponse" name="parameters"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="PingEdiExtServiceSoapImpl">
    <wsdl:operation name="ping">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:ping" name="ping"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:pingResponse" name="pingResponse"/>
      <wsdl:fault message="tns:DachUncheckedExceptionSoap" name="DachUncheckedExceptionSoap"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="PingEdiExtServiceSoapImplServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:PingEdiExtServiceSoapImpl">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="ping">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://com.dachser.edi.ext.api.ping.service.PingEdiExtService" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="ping">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="pingResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="DachUncheckedExceptionSoap">
        <soap:fault name="DachUncheckedExceptionSoap" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="PingEdiExtServiceSoapImplService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:PingEdiExtServiceSoapImplServiceSoapBinding" name="PingEdiExtServiceSoapImplPort">
      <soap:address location="https://edi.dachser.com/soap/ext/pingEdiExtService"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: I am still getting similar error:
Error: src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'tns:dachExceptionData'. It was detected that 'tns:dachExceptionData' is in namespace 'http://com.dachser.edi.ext.api.ping.service.PingEdiExtService', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:/C:/Users/anujkumar/Downloads/wsdl%20test/pingEdiExtService.wsdl'.

Comment: Is it necessary that fault mesage exactly has the namespace http://exception.ws.dachser.com ?
Since you have defined dachExceptionData inside schema which has the namespace com.dachser.edi.ext.api.ping.service.PingEdiExtService you can not use the namespace http://exception.ws.dachser.com.
If you want to separate fault types from message types by using different schemas you have to put complexType name="dachExceptionData" into schema which has the namespace http://exception.ws.dachser.com